# Simulating a list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

What is the proper way to make a div into an ordered list?

Suppose you have this HTML

```html
<div id="list">
    <span>List item one</span>
    <span>List item two</span>
    <span>List item three</span>    
</div>
```

I was under the impression that you wouldn't need to do anything but this

```css
#list {list-style:decimal; margin:1em 0 1em 2.5em;}
#list span {display:list-item}
```

to make it work. And in fact, it *does* work, in all browsers except Mozilla ones. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/CMdvU/). Mozilla doesn't count: all the list items have the number 0.

So have I missed some vital piece of CSS? I did try to put the list-style on the spans too, or only on the spans instead of the div, but that doesn't have any effect.

Is this a bug in Gecko? Or isn't this even supposed to work, and are the other browsers taking liberties with the standards? Internet searches are frustrating, because the results are all about applying styles to `ol` and `ul` elements.

Comment: I hope there's a good reason for not actually using a list element...

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsbin.com/EpohUCE/1/ (But yes, what Madara said...ideally a true list would use actual `li` markup.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Yes, but I found the question was large enough as it was already without going into my motives also. This was the minimal test case I could come up with.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, didn't see the Mozilla part. You are right, Mozilla doesn't seem to know what to do with the numbering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#list {list-style:decimal; margin:1em 0 1em 2.5em;counter-reset: section;}
#list span:before{counter-increment: section; content: counter(section) ".";}
```

....
Only for css3 - including FF.

Comment: Yes, OK, but this doesn't answer the question why Firefox looks differently than all other browsers with display:list-item. I mean, then what is the CSS _for_, if you're not supposed to use it for a numbered list? Your example doesn't require the `list-style` either.

Comment: Ah, I found it. From 1999. [https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4522](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4522). Well, it seems there's nothing to it but to use counters then, if I want to remain cross-browser compatible. Thanks!